# Getting Current ID on Quasar Table

Tags: vue.js, quasar

Good Morning,

I am trying to do and edit feature in a Quasar table.
It works as expected, but when I have more than one entry in the table it defaults to the last entry.

The value of the row is added to the component using props, my problem is getting the current row.
So my question is how do it get the correct row when clicking the button?

[image: Table View]

[image]

[Code Download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag1WF7jnRGVOicxMsUD7f_HrHurLxg?e=NZUC98)

Comment: Is there no slot that exposes the item? Alternatively is there no event emitted with the item as the payload? (sorry not too familiar with Quasar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get row data using `props.row`.

**Example** -

```
<q-table
          title="Treats"
          :data="data"
          :columns="columns"
          row-key="name"
        >
          <template v-slot:body-cell-name="props">
            <q-td :props="props">
              <div>
                <q-badge color="purple" :label="props.value"></q-badge>
                <q-btn icon="edit" dense flat size="sm" @click="EditData(props.row)"></q-btn>
              </div>

            </q-td>
          </template>
        </q-table>


  methods:{
    EditData(row){
      alert("hi")
      console.log(row);
      console.log(this.data.indexOf(row))
    }
  }
```

Now you have a row and `indexof` particular row. You can use `splice` or replace the element on particular index.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/LYVjqXb

Check the console.

Comment: Hi Patel, This is exactly what I am trying to do, but it still going to the last row

Comment: you need to replace the orignal element with updated on the same index.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I'm passing the data to a component, using a dialog, I only get the last row.
What you are saying is correct if the Data is in the same page or component, I already have a function that does exactly that.

Comment: Please check. Put QDialog outside of the table. I think this will work.

Comment: Hi Patel,

After a little more looking into this, the ID is correct, but it pull the wrong data into the component still.

Comment: Please share more information. I have almost done what you need the data is binding correctly. Or share your code.

Comment: You can't use QDialog in Q-Td It will always fill the last row and instead of using prop.row use some selected_row variable.

Comment: Hi Patel, I have added a link to the code (Customers.vue)

Comment: Yeah it works now, except that the dialog window does not want to close even with the v-close-popup in there

Answer (score 0):

**you can use index to get the row number

```html
      <tr v-for="(strockorder,index) in strockorders" :key="index">
      <td class="text-left">{{ strockorder.strockNo}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ strockorder.item}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ strockorder.orderDate}} </td>
      <td class="text-center">{{strockorder.deliveryDate }}</td>
```

**